Behaviour of a function sequence involving integrals
Suppose I have $a_n=\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx$ for positive integer $n$ and continuous function $f$ from $[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, and $b_n=\frac1{n}\int_0^nf(x)dx$. Then, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=2$, can we say that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=2$?
I think the first condition is satisfied by only the constant function. But, how do I prove that? Any hints?

Which condition are you referring to when you say you think it can only be satisfied by a constant function? I do not see any reason in what you have written, why $f$ should be constant.

@Thomas No, you have $b_n = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k$

edited the problem

@Thomas Because, if I take the constant function $f=2$, it satisfies the condition. But, to prove uniqueness, i am not getting ideas

It is not unique. Say $2+\sin(4\pi x)-5e^{-x}$ is also fine. The first term integral from $n$ to $n+1$ is $2$, the second is $0$, and the third will tend to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

As per Andrei's comment which exhibits the counterexample $2 + \sin(4\pi x) - 5e^{-x}$ (although there are simpler counterexamples, Andrei's intent was probably to showcase the variety of counterexamples), $x \mapsto 2 + g(x)$ for any function $g$ such that $\int_n^{n+1} g(x) \mathrm{d} x \to 0$ will satisfy the condition $a_n \to 2$ when $n \to \infty$, so that uniqueness is not met.
Now, the reason why $b_n$ will also tend to $2$ is due to something else: indeed, we have:
$$b_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} a_k$$
so that $b_n$ is what's called the $n$-th Cesàro mean of the sequence $(a_n)_n$.
It's then a classical result-Cesaro Summation that the sequence of the Cesàro means of a convergent sequence is itself convergent and converges to the same limit as the original sequence, and so if $a_n \to \ell \in \mathbb{R}$ then $b_n \to \ell$, $2$ is not some kind of special value here.
